# Why is there 15 principal minors in 4 x 4 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have trouble understanding principal minors.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: 4 x 4 => 1 combinations, 3 x 3 => 4 combinations of submatrix, 2 x 2 = > 3! combinations, 1 x 1 => 4 combinations. So in total 15 principal minors for 4 x 4 matrix Is this correct?

Comment: Your reasoning seems correct, although I don't quite see where you get $2\times2\ \Rightarrow\ 3!$ combinations. What part of understanding principal minors are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a square matrix of dimension $n$. Let $\left[A\right]_{IJ}$ be the matrix consisting of only those rows in $I\subset\left\{ 1,\ldots,n\right\} $ and columns in $J\subset\left\{ 1,\ldots,n\right\} $. If $I=J\neq\emptyset$, $\left[A\right]_{IJ}$ is called a principal minor.

For example, if $n=4$, we can write the original matrix as
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{array}\right].
$$
Removing the first row and first column, we get a principal minor:
$$
\left[A\right]_{IJ}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{array}\right]\text{ where }I=J=\left\{ 2,3,4\right\} .
$$
However, if we had removed just the first row, we would not get a principal minor:
$$
\left[A\right]_{IJ}=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\
a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44}
\end{array}\right]\text{ where }\left\{ 2,3,4\right\} =I\neq J=\left\{ 1,2,3,4\right\} .
$$

See if you can convince yourself that there can only be 15 of these (or in general, $2^n-1$).

Comment: On the 3 x 4 A matrix. Shouldn't i be (2,3,4)? but yes overall, you made the content clear to me now.  Thank you.

Comment: Correct; fixed.