# Number of principal minors

Tags: matrices, lie-algebras

From a [definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1408608/530542) of Principal minors :

Let A be a square matrix of dimension n. Let $\left[A\right]_{IJ}$ be the matrix consisting of only those rows in I⊂{1,…,n} and columns in J⊂{1,…,n}. If I=J≠∅, $\left[A\right]_{IJ}$ is called a principal minor.

There should be a $\left(_k^n\right)$ principal minors for a specific order *k*, and so $\sum _{k=1}^n\left(_k^n\right)$, but sometimes I read that there's $2^n-1$ principal minors.

Can anyone point to me to any reference to a proof

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n-1$

Comment: It is standard that $\;\displaystyle\sum_{k=\color{red}0}^n\binom nk=2^n$.

Comment: yes you're right, I just found an [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_the_binomial_coefficients), Thanks a lot